# Kibana GUI - Adding global 'environment' filter

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Is it possible to add a custom keyword filter to Kibana which would be applied and accessible for modification throughout multiple Kibana tabs like Discover, Dashboards, Visualizations? I'm looking for something like the date filter:
[image]
it's available across multiple tabs and when set, the data is fixed on different tabs/panels until it's changed again. Ideally I need a dropdown with all available environments for our system, something similar to this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a specific index per environment.

It's then quite easy to change indexes via dropdown while keeping your filters and queries in Discover view.

[image: screenshot of dropdown that change the index]

Note that it will not be possible to select all environments and that changing indexes in the Visualization tab is not still possible. It will be necessary in this case to duplicate visualisations by pointing to the respective indexes. This can be done by using the import/export of saved objects.